# Not able to get multiple values from checkbox

Tags: spring, jsp, checkbox

I am trying to access multiple checkbox values from the jsp page.. But i am ending up with wrong bindings..

jsp page:

```
<c:forEach items="${employees}" var="employee">
                    <tr>
                         <td><spring:checkbox path="selectedMails" value="<c:out value='${employee.emailid}'/>"/> </td> 
                        <td><spring:label path="employeeId">${employee.employeeId}</spring:label></td>
                        <td><spring:label path="employeeName">${employee.employeeName}</spring:label></td>
                        <td><spring:label path="emailid" >${employee.emailid}</spring:label></td>
                        <td><spring:label path="reportmanager">${employee.reportmanager}</spring:label></td>

                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
```

dto page

```
//Invitation Beans
    private String [] selectedMails;

    public String [] getSelectedMails() {
        return selectedMails;
    }
    public void setSelectedMails(String [] selectedMails) {
        this.selectedMails = selectedMails;
    }
```

i am able to print `${employee.emailid}` on jsp page.. but i am not able to getting back, and i need more than one values to be saved.. Please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give the arrayindex in the path attribute for each checkbox you create.

Following changes you need to do in your jsp code.

```
<c:forEach items="${employees}" var="employee" varStatus="cnt">
    <tr> 
        <td><spring:checkbox path="selectedMails[${cnt.index}]" value="<c:out value='${employee.emailid}'/>"/> </td>  
        <td><spring:label path="employeeId">${employee.employeeId}</spring:label></td> 
        <td><spring:label path="employeeName">${employee.employeeName}</spring:label></td> 
        <td><spring:label path="emailid" >${employee.emailid}</spring:label></td> 
        <td><spring:label path="reportmanager">${employee.reportmanager}</spring:label></td> 
    </tr> 
</c:forEach>
```

I think this should work for you.

Hope this helps you.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

To get more than one value you should have more than one checkbox with same name. In that case it will be putted in request as an array and you can get this values as array.

If you have single checkbox - you will get single value. Or no value at all if checkbox not checked. It not put any value to request in case if checkbox is not checked.

Comment: yes you are right.... but if u see my jsp code you will come to know that i have used a single checkbox in a loop with single variable.. still i am not able to get those values in array..

Comment: Maybe type should be Boolean?